# Unity не открывает Visual Studio 2019. Кнопка скрипта не реагирует

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio, файлы

Я нажимаю на кнопку скрипта, как обычно, два раза кликнув. Но он никак не реагирует, не открывает Visual Studio 2019. В Preferences у Unity уже стоит этот VS. Путь к VS указан правильно. [image: Вот я пытаюсь открыть его в Project-е][image: Вот VS в Preferences]

Comment: c данной проблемой не сталкивался,но если не найдете решение то есть прекрасная VS Code :)

Comment: Возможно, поможет открыть проект один раз вручную. Я пользуюсь райдером, мне помогало.

Comment: Я уже пробовал вручную, но VS не видит его как элемент Unity.

Comment: Такая же проблема. Как решить в итоге? Поставить старую версию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В способе открытия файлов укажи 1 пункт (Open by file extension). Мне помогло. Я использовал до этого VS Code. После переключения он стал открывать в нем же.

Answer (score 2):

У меня было что-то похожее. Мне помогло убрать галочку с пункта "Editor Attaching". Он находится прямо под выбором редактора в Unity (он есть у вас на скриншоте).

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае помогло выбрать испольнительный файл редактора через кнопку Browse

Comment: Исполнительный файл? exe-шник чтоли? Если да, то я уже это сделал.

Comment: @Spasibo, удаляли папку .vs из директории игры? и все .csproj и .sln в придачу?

Comment: ничего я не удалял...

Comment: Короче, я через .sln открыл скрипт, но вопрос еще будет стоять на StackOv.

Comment: @Spasibo, так это я посоветовал удалить всё это перед запуском)

Answer (score 0):

Установите версию 2019.1.3 и должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло переименование папки проекта в латиницу, без пробелов.